# GDAL Install Inside of Docker Container/Image Ubuntu

Tags: python, gdal, docker

I am trying to ensure GDAL and it's dependencies are installed as part of my Docker container/image.  My current Linux environment is Ubuntu 20.04.  My end goal would be to run bin/bash GDAL based commands from a console and/or web application that is packaged as it's own Docker container, as well as execute python scripts utilizing the gdal libraries in the end.

I have tried looking at the Dockerfile at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/gdal/docker/ubuntu-full, and brought in the associated .sh files that it appears to need to install.  However, when I build the .NET core console application using Docker build, it doesn't appear as any of the GDAL installation pieces are running.

I'd have no problem either getting it to work via bringing the pieces of the Dockerfile from there and the associated .sh scripts, or just straight up referencing the image and using Docker Compose to create a dependency, but not matter what I try, when I try to run a process to execute /bin/bash commands, I get the following message:

> /bin/bash: gdalinfo: No such file or directory

I'm sure someone out there has attempted to do this before, and I hope I am at least getting close to the answer, but at this point I am totally stumped.  Can someone offer some guidance on the best route or what I may be missing?

Here's my Dockerfile attempting to build and install the gdal dependencies, that appears to do nothing on the entire GDAL side of things:

```
##
# osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-full

# This file is available at the option of the licensee under:
# Public domain
# or licensed under X/MIT (LICENSE.TXT) Copyright 2019 Even Rouault <even.rouault@spatialys.com>

ARG BASE_IMAGE=ubuntu:20.04

FROM $BASE_IMAGE as builder

# Derived from osgeo/proj by Howard Butler <howard@hobu.co>
LABEL maintainer="Even Rouault <even.rouault@spatialys.com>"

# Setup build env for PROJ
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --fix-missing --no-install-recommends \
            software-properties-common build-essential ca-certificates \
            git make cmake wget unzip libtool automake \
            zlib1g-dev libsqlite3-dev pkg-config sqlite3 libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
            libtiff5-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ARG JAVA_VERSION=11
# Setup build env for GDAL
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --fix-missing --no-install-recommends \
       libcharls-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libcairo2-dev \
       python3-dev python3-numpy \
       libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev liblzma-dev libgeos-dev \
       curl libxml2-dev libexpat-dev libxerces-c-dev \
       libnetcdf-dev libpoppler-dev libpoppler-private-dev \
       libspatialite-dev swig ant libhdf4-alt-dev libhdf5-serial-dev \
       libfreexl-dev unixodbc-dev libwebp-dev libepsilon-dev \
       liblcms2-2 libpcre3-dev libcrypto++-dev libdap-dev libfyba-dev \
       libkml-dev libmysqlclient-dev libogdi-dev \
       libcfitsio-dev openjdk-"$JAVA_VERSION"-jdk libzstd-dev \
       libpq-dev libssl-dev libboost-dev \
       autoconf automake bash-completion libarmadillo-dev \
       libopenexr-dev libheif-dev \
       libdeflate-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Build likbkea
ARG KEA_VERSION=1.4.13
RUN wget -q https://github.com/ubarsc/kealib/archive/kealib-${KEA_VERSION}.zip \
    && unzip -q kealib-${KEA_VERSION}.zip \
    && rm -f kealib-${KEA_VERSION}.zip \
    && cd kealib-kealib-${KEA_VERSION} \
    && cmake . -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DHDF5_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/hdf5/serial \
        -DHDF5_LIB_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial -DLIBKEA_WITH_GDAL=OFF \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install DESTDIR="/build_thirdparty" \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf kealib-kealib-${KEA_VERSION} \
    && for i in /build_thirdparty/usr/lib/*; do strip -s $i 2>/dev/null || /bin/true; done \
    && for i in /build_thirdparty/usr/bin/*; do strip -s $i 2>/dev/null || /bin/true; done

# Build mongo-c-driver
ARG MONGO_C_DRIVER_VERSION=1.16.2
RUN mkdir mongo-c-driver \
    && wget -q https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases/download/${MONGO_C_DRIVER_VERSION}/mongo-c-driver-${MONGO_C_DRIVER_VERSION}.tar.gz -O - \
        | tar xz -C mongo-c-driver --strip-components=1 \
    && cd mongo-c-driver \
    && mkdir build_cmake \
    && cd build_cmake \
    && cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DENABLE_TESTS=NO -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install DESTDIR="/build_thirdparty" \
    && make install \
    && cd ../.. \
    && rm -rf mongo-c-driver \
    && rm /build_thirdparty/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*.a \
    && for i in /build_thirdparty/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*; do strip -s $i 2>/dev/null || /bin/true; done \
    && for i in /build_thirdparty/usr/bin/*; do strip -s $i 2>/dev/null || /bin/true; done

# Build mongocxx
ARG MONGOCXX_VERSION=3.5.0
RUN mkdir mongocxx \
    && wget -q https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/archive/r${MONGOCXX_VERSION}.tar.gz -O - \
        | tar xz -C mongocxx --strip-components=1 \
    && cd mongocxx \
    && mkdir build_cmake \
    && cd build_cmake \
    && cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=ON -DMONGOCXX_ENABLE_SLOW_TESTS=NO -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_VERSION=${MONGOCXX_VERSION} \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install DESTDIR="/build_thirdparty" \
    && make install \
    && cd ../.. \
    && rm -rf mongocxx \
    && for i in /build_thirdparty/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*; do strip -s $i 2>/dev/null || /bin/true; done \
    && for i in /build_thirdparty/usr/bin/*; do strip -s $i 2>/dev/null || /bin/true; done

# Build tiledb
ARG TILEDB_VERSION=2.0.8
RUN mkdir tiledb \
    && wget -q https://github.com/TileDB-Inc/TileDB/archive/${TILEDB_VERSION}.tar.gz -O - \
        | tar xz -C tiledb --strip-components=1 \
    && cd tiledb \
    && mkdir build_cmake \
    && cd build_cmake \
    && ../bootstrap --prefix=/usr \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install-tiledb DESTDIR="/build_thirdparty" \
    && make install-tiledb \
    && cd ../.. \
    && rm -rf tiledb \
    && for i in /build_thirdparty/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*; do strip -s $i 2>/dev/null || /bin/true; done \
    && for i in /build_thirdparty/usr/bin/*; do strip -s $i 2>/dev/null || /bin/true; done

# Build openjpeg
ARG OPENJPEG_VERSION=
RUN if test "${OPENJPEG_VERSION}" != ""; then ( \
    wget -q https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/archive/v${OPENJPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar xzf v${OPENJPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && rm -f v${OPENJPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && cd openjpeg-${OPENJPEG_VERSION} \
    && cmake . -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON  -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install \
    && mkdir -p /build_thirdparty/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    && rm -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so* \
    && mv /usr/lib/libopenjp2.so* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    && cp -P /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so* /build_thirdparty/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    && for i in /build_thirdparty/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*; do strip -s $i 2>/dev/null || /bin/true; done \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf openjpeg-${OPENJPEG_VERSION} \
    ); fi

# Install MDB Driver Jars
RUN wget -q https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/mdb-sqlite/mdb-sqlite-1.0.2.tar.bz2 \
  && tar -xjf mdb-sqlite-1.0.2.tar.bz2 \
  && mkdir -p /build/usr/share/java \
  && cp mdb-sqlite-1.0.2/lib/*.jar /build/usr/share/java \
  && rm -rf mdb-sqlite-1.0.2.tar.bz2 && rm -rf mdb-sqlite-1.0.2

#Set CLASSPATH so jars are found
ENV CLASSPATH="/build/usr/share/java/jackcess-1.1.14.jar:/build/usr/share/java/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/build/usr/share/java/commons-lang-2.4.jar"

#Build File Geodatabase

ARG WITH_FILEGDB=
RUN if echo "$WITH_FILEGDB" | grep -Eiq "^(y(es)?|1|true)$"  ; then ( \
  wget -q https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api/raw/master/FileGDB_API_1.5.1/FileGDB_API_1_5_1-64gcc51.tar.gz \
  && tar -xzf FileGDB_API_1_5_1-64gcc51.tar.gz \
  && chown -R root:root FileGDB_API-64gcc51 \
  && mv FileGDB_API-64gcc51 /usr/local/FileGDB_API \
  && rm -rf /usr/local/FileGDB_API/lib/libstdc++* \
  && cp /usr/local/FileGDB_API/lib/* /build_thirdparty/usr/lib \
  && cp /usr/local/FileGDB_API/include/* /usr/include \
  && rm -rf FileGDB_API_1_5_1-64gcc51.tar.gz \
  ) ; fi



RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y --fix-missing --no-install-recommends rsync ccache \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ARG RSYNC_REMOTE

ARG WITH_DEBUG_SYMBOLS=no

# Build PROJ
ARG PROJ_VERSION=master
ARG PROJ_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
COPY ./bh-proj.sh /buildscripts/bh-proj.sh
RUN /buildscripts/bh-proj.sh

ARG GDAL_VERSION=master
ARG GDAL_RELEASE_DATE
ARG GDAL_BUILD_IS_RELEASE

# Build GDAL
COPY ./bh-gdal.sh /buildscripts/bh-gdal.sh
RUN /buildscripts/bh-gdal.sh

# Build final image
FROM $BASE_IMAGE as runner

RUN date
ARG JAVA_VERSION=11

RUN apt-get update \
# PROJ dependencies
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        libsqlite3-0 libtiff5 libcurl4 \
        wget curl unzip ca-certificates \
# GDAL dependencies
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        libcharls2 libopenjp2-7 libcairo2 python3-numpy \
        libpng16-16 libjpeg-turbo8 libgif7 liblzma5 libgeos-3.8.0 libgeos-c1v5 \
        libxml2 libexpat1 \
        libxerces-c3.2 libnetcdf-c++4 netcdf-bin libpoppler97 libspatialite7 gpsbabel \
        libhdf4-0-alt libhdf5-103 libhdf5-cpp-103 poppler-utils libfreexl1 unixodbc libwebp6 \
        libepsilon1 liblcms2-2 libpcre3 libcrypto++6 libdap25 libdapclient6v5 libfyba0 \
        libkmlbase1 libkmlconvenience1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1 libkmlregionator1 libkmlxsd1 \
        libmysqlclient21 libogdi4.1 libcfitsio8 openjdk-"$JAVA_VERSION"-jre \
        libzstd1 bash bash-completion libpq5 libssl1.1 \
        libarmadillo9 libpython3.8 libopenexr24 libheif1 \
        libdeflate0 \
        python-is-python3 \
    # Workaround bug in ogdi packaging
    && ln -s /usr/lib/ogdi/libvrf.so /usr/lib \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Attempt to order layers starting with less frequently varying ones

COPY --from=builder  /build_thirdparty/usr/ /usr/

ARG PROJ_DATUMGRID_LATEST_LAST_MODIFIED
ARG PROJ_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
COPY --from=builder  /build${PROJ_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/proj/ ${PROJ_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/proj/
COPY --from=builder  /build${PROJ_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/ ${PROJ_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/
COPY --from=builder  /build${PROJ_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/ ${PROJ_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/
COPY --from=builder  /build${PROJ_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/ ${PROJ_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/
RUN ldconfig \
    && projsync --system-directory --all

COPY --from=builder  /build/usr/share/java /usr/share/java
COPY --from=builder  /build/usr/share/gdal/ /usr/share/gdal/
COPY --from=builder  /build/usr/include/ /usr/include/
COPY --from=builder  /build_gdal_python/usr/ /usr/
COPY --from=builder  /build_gdal_version_changing/usr/ /usr/

RUN ldconfig

#Set CLASSPATH so jars are found
ENV CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/jackcess-1.1.14.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-lang-2.4.jar"

#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#CONSOLE APPLICATION
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish "Satellites.Console.csproj" -c Release -o out

# Build the runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Satellites.Console.dll"]
```

And here is what I've attempted to do in a .yaml for the Compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    gdal:
        image: "geodata/gdal:ubuntu-full-3.2.0"
    satellites.console:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}satellitesconsole
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Satellites.Console/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - gdal
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?  I have noticed that if I don't have the portion in the Dockerfile to run the console, everything gets installed correctly.  As soon as I add the Console section, all the installations are totally skipped over.  What's causing this?

Comment: if you're still working on this...
Can you confirm that GDAL works for you without the extra console install bits in your modified Dockerfile?
Assuming that you _can_ run the "stock" GDAL / Ubuntu Docker container (from the GDAL GitHub repo), can you test your extra console install steps from a terminal/shell into the running GDAL Docker container?

Comment: Also, this might be a good resource as well:
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GDAL-Dev-f3742093.html